# underscore _.each not adding property to object element

Tags: javascript, mongoose, underscore.js

This is kind of a newb question as there are still some small things about javascript that baffle me.

I have the following code:

```
db.units.find({}, { _id: 1, type: 1, name: 1 }).sort({ type: 1, name: 1}).exec(function(err, units) {

  if(err) return next(err);

  _.each(units, function(u, i) {
    this[i]["available"] = !_.contains(_.pluck(_.pluck(req.workorder.units, 'unit'), 'name'), u.name);

    console.log(this[i].available);  
    console.log(this[i]);  
    console.log(_.extend(this[i],{available:this[i].available}));
  }, units); 


  return res.render('workorder/show', {
    workorder: req.workorder,
    invoices: db.invoices.find({ workorders: req.params.id }),
    units: units
  });
});
```

and here is the result:

true
{ _id: 513bd489b0e7e2634b60dc47,
  name: 'Visual Sump Inspection UST-22C NC',
  type: 'Service' }

its is logging the available property but not in the object alone, why is this?

Comment: Instead of `console.log()`, put a `debugger;` statement in there. Then when you run it, it will stop in the JavaScript debugger and you can explore the object data interactively. This can make it much easier when you're not sure of the data format.

Comment: @MichaelGeary this code happens to be running on the server side

Comment: can it be that "this[i]" object has its toString() method overriden

Comment: @nilgundag that is not the issue

Comment: What do you mean by "its is logging the available property but not in the object alone, why is this?"

Comment: Don't use `this[i]`, but just `u`!

Comment: Definitely agree with Bergi. And once you change all your `this[i]` references to `u`, you can remove `, i` from the parameter list for the `.each` callback since it won't be used. I'd also be inclined to call it `unit` instead of `u` to be consistent with the `units` array, but that's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to how mongoose treats objects. the object can only be modified with the  usage of document.toObject()

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Likeso:

```
  _.each(units, function(u, i) {
    u = _.extend(u.toObject(), {'available': !_.contains(_.pluck(_.pluck(req.workorder.units, 'unit'), 'name'), u.name)});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Mongoose is defining the `available` property in a way that makes it readable but non-enumerable. It could be using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters), or it could be setting `enumerable: false` with an [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) call.

For a quick test, try pasting this code into the Chrome console or in your node.js app:

```
var obj = { a: 1 };
Object.defineProperties( obj, {
    b: {
        get: function() {
            return 2;
        }
    },
    c: {
        value: 3,
        enumerable: false
    }
});
console.log( obj );
console.log( obj.a );
console.log( obj.b );
console.log( obj.c );
```

In Chrome, the code logs:

```
Object {a: 1}
1
2
3
```

So all three properties are showing up when read explicitly, but `b` and `c` are not enumerated when the object as a whole is logged.